# Cumulative Frequency with Defined Bins in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of data on how quickly people take action measured in hours. I want to generate a table that tells me what % of users have taken by the first hour, first day, first week, first month, etc.

I have used the `pandas.cut` to categorize and give them `group_names`

`bins_hours = [0...]
group_names = [...]
hourlylook = pd.cut(av.date_diff, bins_hours, labels=group_names,right=False)`

I then plotted hourlylook and got an awesome bar chart.

But I want to express this information cumulatively, too, in a table format. What's the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html
This should allow you to create a new column with the cumulative sum.